# Is there any JQuery that would help embedding excel spreadsheet for a webpage?

Tags: jquery, html, excel, embed

There are many ways to embed using `CNTRL+S`, or Google Documents, or some cool tool like [this](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/09/embed-interactive-excel-spreadsheets.html)

However Google docs and that tool require the document to stay on some remote server. However. I must have all my documents to be on my drive. So is there any JQuery that would at least somehow allow for those interactive features as [zoho](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/09/embed-interactive-excel-spreadsheets.html)  and at the same time allow to keep the documents on my drive only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking if it is possible to use one of the online spreadsheet solutions OFFLINE disconnected from the internet.

It is possible to use google docs offline:
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/1628467?hl=en

There may be some limitations but you should be able to have basic functionality.